# asyncio.subprocess always blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I need to write some async code which runs a subprocess as part of its tasks. Even though I am using asyncio.subprocess my code is still blocking. My server looks like this:

```
import asyncio
import asyncio.subprocess
import websockets

async def handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        print('I received a message')
        player = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            'sleep', '5',
            stdin=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL)
        await player.wait()
        print('Finished waiting')

server = websockets.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', '8000')
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

And a very basic client:

import asyncio
import websockets

```
async def client():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000') as websocket:
        for i in range(5):
            await websocket.send('message')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(client())
```

I would expect the output to look like this:

```
I received a message
I received a message
I received a message
I received a message
I received a message
Finished waiting
Finished waiting
Finished waiting
Finished waiting
Finished waiting
```

But instead I get this:

```
I received a message
Finished waiting
I received a message
Finished waiting
I received a message
Finished waiting
I received a message
Finished waiting
I received a message
Finished waiting
```

With a 5 second wait after each "I received a message" line.

Comment: Did you read https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/ ?

Comment: (I have updated my answer below with a reference to `ensure_future()`)

Answer (score 2):

The line `await player.wait()` does not block other async operations, but waits for 5 seconds!

If you don't want to wait for the response, try using `ensure_future()` instead:

```
# add:
async def wait_for_player(player, path):
    print("Waiting...", path)
    await player.wait()
    print("Done", path)

# and replace await player.wait() with:
asyncio.ensure_future(wait_for_player(player, path))
```

You can actually also move `create_subprocess_exec()` to `wait_for_player()`.

---

To see your code is not blocking see try these:

Client:

```
import asyncio

import websockets


async def client(n):
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000/{}/'.format(n)) as websocket:
        print(n, "start")
        for i in range(5):
            print(n, i)
            await websocket.send('message')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print(n, "done")


tasks = [client(i) for i in range(5)]
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

Server:

```
import asyncio
import asyncio.subprocess

import random
import websockets


async def handler(websocket, path):
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            pause = random.randint(1, 5)
            print('I received a message', path, "Pausing:", pause)
            player = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
                'sleep', str(pause),
                stdin=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL,
                stdout=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL,
                stderr=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL)
            await player.wait()
            print('Finished waiting', path)
    except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
        print("Connection closed!", path)


server = websockets.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', '8000')
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: This server example still appears to be blocking? Merging your first example into the larger server example works perfectly. I used a slightly different API using asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(...), but that should be equivalent afaics.

Comment: It is not blocking - you can see *other* clients can still communicate with the server while `wait()` is pausing one client.p

Comment: My main problem was that the one client should also not be blocked; I happen to only have a single client .

Comment: So just use `ensure_future()` (or `create_task()`) as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Your ws server seems ok. Actually it is your client that is blocking. If you want to test the async behavior of your server, You need to make asynchronous requests. The for loop in your client blocks the thread. So remove it and instead, use `asyncio.gather` to run your `client()` method 5 times asynchronously

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def client():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000') as websocket:
        await websocket.send('message')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


tasks = asyncio.gather(*[client() for i in range(5)])
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(tasks)
```

Comment: They are actually both blocking.. mea culpa